# Checking if some textbox is empty and then running event in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, events

I am going to make a simple userform for finding value and display results in ListBox.
I have a 15 textboxes and one button for finding. Source of data for finding is always the same. Only input value (for finding) will dynamic.
My conception is:

1. Declarate one public variable and this will be input value
2. checking if some textbox is empty
3. If not, declarate variable will TextBox.Value (which is not empty) and execute finding method

What is the problem? Generally, I can write a lot of codes for all textboxes
For example:

```
  If TextBox1.Value <> "" Then 
    ' execute finding method - input is TextBox1.Value
    ElseIf TextBox2.Value <> "" Then 
    ' execute finding method - input is TextBox2.Value
   ...
```

And generate 15x ElseIf or secound option create separately button. It will looks funny 15 buttons.

But a both solution are not perfect.
How can I implement good solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My conception is:

> 1. Declarate one public variable and this will be input value
> 2. checking if some textbox is empty
> 3. If not, declarate variable will TextBox.Value (which is not empty) and execute finding method

Is this what you are trying?

```
Dim MyValue As String
Dim cCont As Control

'~~> Loop through all textboxes
For Each cCont In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(cCont) = "TextBox" Then
        If Len(Trim(cCont.Value)) <> 0 Then
            '~~> Set the value and exit the loop
            MyValue = cCont.Value
        Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next cCont
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I know exactly what the issue is here (or why you might want 15 buttons...) but this should work:

```vb
Dim v, i as Long

For i = 1 to 15
    v = Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value
    If Len(v) > 0 Then Exit For
Next i

'do something with v
```

Comment: I will try explain in another words. I have 15 TextBoxes and this is my input for finding value. All TextBoxes can use the same method of finding, but diffrent of course will input data (value searched). Example: TextBoxe1 - Name, TextBoxe2 - Surname, TextBoxe3 - Company etc. and for handle of "find" evening I would like to use only one button.